# pandas: aggregate rows for a given column and count the number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame `my_df`:

```
team      member
--------------------    
 A         Mary
 B         John
 C         Amy
 A         Dan
 B         Dave
 D         Paul
 B         Alex
 A         Mary
 D         Mary
```

I want the new output the new data frame `new_df` as:

```
team      members              number
--------------------------------------
 A       [Mary,Dan]              2
 B       [John,Dave,Alex]        3
 C       [Amy]                   1
 D       [Paul,Mary]             2
```

I am wondering is there any existing pandas function can perform the above task? Thanks!

Comment: Can there be repeat names in the member column?  If so, should they be double counted, or only counted once?

Comment: Assuming the same team won't have the same name, but a name can show in different teams. Modified the example above. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `groupby`

***`pd.concat`***

```
g = df.groupby('team').member
pd.concat([g.apply(list), g.count()], axis=1, keys=['members', 'number'])
```

***`agg`***

```
g = df.groupby('team').member
g.agg(dict(members=lambda x: list(x), number='count'))

                 members  number
team                            
A            [Mary, Dan]       2
B     [John, Dave, Alex]       3
C                  [Amy]       1
D                 [Paul]       1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option here:

```
(df.groupby("team", as_index=False).member
   .agg({"member": lambda x: list(x), "count": "count"}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

using `lambda`:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame()
newdf['team']=my_df['team'].unique()
newdf['members']=newdf['team'].map(lambda x:list(my_df[my_df['team']==x]['member']))
newdf['number']=newdf.members.map(lambda x: len(x))
newdf.set_index('team',inplace=True)
```